# Using phpseclib with a custom shell wrapper

Tags: php, shell, phpseclib, dokku, dokku-alt

I am using PHPSeclib to access server with dokku-alt installed:

http://dokku-alt.github.io/how-it-works.html

By following a typical example, I manage to send commands to a custom shell on my account:

```
    $ssh=$this->connect();
    echo trim($ssh->exec("version");
```

This is equivalent to

```
ssh dokku@my.node.org version
```

and works as expected. If I however try to execute a command which expects me to send data through STDIN, there is a problem. According to Net_SSH2 documentation, I need to `write` the data into SSH stream instead of using exec(). Unfortunately my next example does not work, because custom shell does not receive any argument and responds with help page:

```
    $ssh=$this->connect();
    $ssh->write("mysql mariadb:console myapp newdb\n");
    $ssh->write("show tables\n");
    $ssh->read('[prompt]');
```

The result of this is identical to

```
ssh dokku@my.node.org
```

which simply responds with help page.

How can I combine the "exec" functionality and still be able to write data? Something like this does not work either:

```
    $ssh=$this->connect();
    $ssh->exec("mysql mariadb:console myapp newdb");
    $ssh->write("show tables\n");
    $ssh->read('[prompt]');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think PTY mode is what you're looking for? eg.

```
$ssh->enablePTY(); 
$ssh->exec('mysql mariadb:console myapp newdb'); 
echo $ssh->read('mysql>'); 
$ssh->write("show tables\n");
echo $ssh->read('mysql>');
```

More info:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html

Comment: great! That worked as required, although I skipped first read() and the last read() had no arguments.